# Small microcontroller with USB host peripheral

Tags: microcontroller, usb, stm32, microchip, usb-host

I'm trying to find microcontroller with low pin coutn that has USB host capabilities.

I know this can be done with big PIC24 or PIC33 microcontrollers, but I wonder if there are others chips that can do , easily.

Comment: Apart from being categorically off topic, small does not mean few pins, it typically means QFN or something chip scale.  There are plenty of embedded host MCU's in QFN packages for example KLZ25 in a QFN32.  Writing embedded USB host code is not trivial however!

Comment: I've never seen an 8- or 16-bit processor (including the PIC33) that has USB host capability. I'm pretty sure you need to look at 32-bit processors (e.g., PIC32, ARM) to get that capability. Some of them are fairly small.

Comment: @DaveTweed playing with an online catalog suggests there are a number of PIC24 parts and possibly the AVR-based AT90USB646 etc that would qualify as 8/16 bit cores with limited host capability.  I see little reason to pick any of them over something more modern, except perhaps for the novelty of one of the DIP parts.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Actually, I lie -- I was aware of the [FTDI Vinculum family](https://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/VNC2.htm), which has a 16-bit core and was designed specifically for USB host capability. You can get it in a 32-pin LQFN package, which is pretty damn small (7mm square).

Answer (score 1):

If your only goal is retrieving serial data from the uP, any micro with a EUSART module will output serial data, then just hook up a "ttl-232r-5V" type cable.

No need for any usb host modules. I regularly use the PIC12f1572 for this type of thing. An 8 pin micro with adc, dac and eusart as well as a few other bits and pieces is more than enough for most of my projects. I buy them in bulk for around 0.30 gpb each.

Comment: Indeed sounds like an XY problem, and that USB could be eliminated altogether

Comment: actually i do need the usb HOST capabilities , serial usb , was only an example...